# How to add non-public repositories from command line with composer?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I want to add a new package which is not at packagist, it's a local or non-public repository. I know how to this in the `composer.json`. For example:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxxx.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "xxxx/xxxxx": "dev-master"
},
```

But I want to do this from the command line so that I can add this non-public repositories in a provision file.
Packages registered at Packagist I can add with:

```
composer require ....
```

But how to handle this with repositories not registered at Packagist?

Answer (score 95):

You can run the following from the project root to add a repository to the project's composer.json:

```
composer config repositories.repo-name vcs https://github.com/<orgname or username>/repo
```

Then you can require the specific repo with:

```
composer require <orgname or username>/repo:dev-branchname
```

---

The Composer documentation covers it at [*Modifying Repositories* (CLI: composer config)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-repositories).

Comment: and then add the package with `composer require package-name:dev-branchname`.

Comment: this broke the json of my composer.json :D I wanted to run it command line to do it by the book and not hack composer.json but oh well .D that worked at least :P

Comment: Pro tip: you can use `repositories.0` to avoid it from breaking its own json file

Comment: To avoid overwrites when you want to add multiple repos, you can just replace `repo-name` with your own string.

Comment: `repositories.0` is not a valid solution, I just thought so as well, but it replaces the first entry and does not insert the new one before the first entry

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation for this command:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-repositories